# Hadoop Pig Latin, CONCAT function fails

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have tried all the permutations I can think of, but I can't get CONCAT to work.

When I try:

fake = load CONCAT('foo','bar');

I get the following:

2013-01-17 12:41:44,443 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200:   mismatched input 'CONCAT' expecting QUOTEDSTRING

I have tried double quotes which I wouldn't expect to work and indeed doesn't; I have tried
passing in parameters to the script and using CONCAT on them and I get the same error.

To motivate this, I am trying to specify a base output directory which gets concatenated with various possible sub output directories depending upon where I want result files.

BTW, I have also tried:

fake = LOAD 'foo'+'bar';

That is, no use of CONCAT.

I am using the pig-0.10.1.jar -- I think this is latest version.

Comment: Well, the error tells you whats wrong. You should provide `LOAD` with a (single) quoted string as specified in http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#LOAD)

Comment: Right, although I was trying it also with a STORE which is what I really wanted -- so what seems to be is that places where a single quoted string is required are not also places where CONCAT can be used? Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call `CONCAT` directly within the `LOAD`, but you actually don't need to. You could define parameter constants that you would either specify in the script with `%declare` or by passing command line parameters/parameter file. Then you can resolve the parameters with the `$x` notation, and concatenation is implicit like in shell scripts:

```
%declare FOO 'foo'
%declare BAR 'bar'

fake = load '$FOO$BAR';
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion -- two questions: 1. I am trying to call CONCAT from STORE as I sort of implied. In neither load or store is the error saying anything like can't call CONCAT but rather the QUOTEDSTRING error -- should CONCAT work within STORE? 2. Why can't you call CONCAT from within LOAD?

Comment: Thanks, just as you said. Not sure whether I was missing something stated in the documentation for Pig Latin or it is simply unclear, but doing something like load '$FOO$BAR' got me what I needed -- did not use CONCAT.